# Are any JoJo's anime related?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

I started with the latest one the one, *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure: Golden Wind* and came to know that the anime is even older. Found many series dating back to 2012. So, as I started watching the 2012 series, I saw that it is a vampire genre. Vampire -> Stand. I don't see any connection.

I saw a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/cpCcSwkw7L4?t=254) of the strongest immortal characters and there's a listing of a character from these anime. So, I don't want to miss any connection if there is one, as I am planning to skip the 2012 series because of its genre (vampire).

Are any JoJo's anime related?

Comment: Golden Wind is part 5, meaning you missed out on parts 1 through 4.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think it's fair to say that the series is in the "vampire genre". Some characters in the first seasons are called vampires, but it's never the focal point of the story. If that's the only thing keeping your from the earlier seasons, I would give them a try regardless. I personally think the first few episodes were quite bad, but it got better quickly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, they are connected. Just from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JoJo%27s_Bizarre_Adventure_(TV_series)) about Season 1 (the 2012 series),

> The first season aired in Japan between October 5, 2012 and April 5, 2013, with episodes 1-9 covering the Phantom Blood arc, and episodes 10-26 covering the Battle Tendency arc. **The first part follows a young man named Jonathan Joestar** who becomes involved in a battle against Dio Brando, who uses the power of a mysterious Stone Mask to become a vampire. **The second part takes place fifty years later as Jonathan's grandson, Joseph Joestar**, faces up against the Stone Mask's creators, the Pillar Men.

while for Season 2,

> The second season, titled JoJo's Bizarre Adventure: Stardust Crusaders, **adapts the series third story arc**, Stardust Crusaders. Set in 1987, **the story follows Joseph's grandson, Jotaro Kujo**, and his companions as they seek to defeat DIO, who has placed a curse on his mother, using special abilities known as Stands.

as per the premise,

> JoJo's Bizarre Adventure tells the story of the Joestar family, a family whose various members discover they are destined to take down supernatural foes using powers that they possess. The story is split up into unique parts, each following one member of the Joestar family, who inevitably has a name that can be abbreviated to the titular "JoJo".

you can see that the series are connected directly by the fact that they follow the Joestar family, and Season 1 and 2 are connected beyond that just the bloodline as [on the *Stardust Crusaders* Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardust_Crusaders)

> Joseph explains that the sudden appearance of Stands among the Joestar bloodline is caused by the nemesis of his grandfather, Jonathan Joestar: the vampire Dio Brando. Having succeeded in taking Jonathan's body after his assumed demise in the 19th century and resurfacing a few years prior, Dio has awoken his own Stand and recruited Stand-using assassins to kill Jonathan's remaining descendants.