# What is the connection between Stands and Ripple Energy?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

I don't understand how Stands are connected to the Ripple Energy, which is from breathing. The third part does not seem that linked to the first two parts of JoJo.

Comment: this one might help: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49650/are-any-jojos-anime-related

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, the Stand is supposed to be an extension of the Ripple, but I’d have to look it up again to know the exact details.

Answer (score 3):

I’m a third of the way through Part 3, and as far as I can tell, there’s minimal, if any at all, link between Stand and Hamon (Ripple) abilities. Initially, I thought the Stand was an extension of Hamon, since there’s a remark about Jotaro’s ability to fight while unable to breathe in his initial fight with Avdol, which other people on the internet have also noticed, but this doesn’t amount to much.

Discussions I found in a web search attest to this as well:

- [This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/StardustCrusaders/comments/5njb5j/are_stands_an_evolution_of_hamon/) and [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Hirohiko-Araki-essentially-do-away-with-The-Ripple-Hamon-Sado-by-the-time-he-wrote-JJBA-Part-3-Stardust-Crusaders) discuss the relationship between Stand and Ripple. Posters cite Part 7, in which Hamon is indicated to be a stepping stone to Stand. (I haven’t gotten to Part 7, so I can’t judge for myself on the details.) However, this is seen as a retcon, and for the most part, people seem inclined to say that there’s not much relationship.
- The [fan wiki article on Stand](http://jojo.wikia.com/wiki/Stand) and [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/StardustCrusaders/comments/3h55rs/any_reason_why_araki_dropped_hamonripple/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=comment_header), among other sources, note that Hamon was more or less discarded after Part 2.

Answer (score 2):

### My Explanation

So, I think that due to someone using Hamon creates a Hamon current( ,similar to electricity,), and stands conduct Hamon, and I think that's how Old Joseph can send Hamon through his stand.
I have also collected a paragraph from a Fandom page showing Ripple Transmission through Hermit Purple.

### Ripple Transmission

Joseph has shown the ability to transmit the Ripple through Hermit Purple as an extension of his body. Joseph has used this property of Hermit Purple to attack DIO or prevent him from touching him by wrapping himself in it.

Comment: By the way, Young Joseph uses clackers, and is showcased in part 2, not part 3.